# Is it possible to combine AngularJS, HTML5, and CSS3 as front end, and NodeJS as back end ,PHP5 as rest web service?

Tags: php, node.js, html, css

I'am newer in PHP development.I have a question please.Is there any way to create a web application with AngularJS,HTML5,CSS3 as front end,and NodeJS as back end,ans PHP5 as a restful web service?

Comment: Sure, it's possible.

Comment: thanks @prodigitalson for your reply,I followed an article from the net and it said that There are a few limitations in the implementation for example, it will only remember one connection from each user if we combine those technologies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lot of examples with angularjs,nodejs in web and if you want to use php as rest service for any reason,

You may use node.js **request** library for this - 
Examples are provided in - https://github.com/request/request

Your client side ajax code should direct to node.js application server and then from node.js server, you can send request through the above and on callback of the code (here you can use node.js promise),you will have the result, which you can return as response to your ajax callback...

Also to note, if you code carefully, there is no such limitation as you indicated in the question...

Hope this will help you.

Thanks

Comment: in the exemple that you mentionned,can you explain more please how can I use the PHP service,to send information to data Base may be :)